# Are there any good Hulu, Veoh or Youtube alternatives?

Tags: video, webapp-rec

Unfortunately services like [Hulu](http://www.hulu.com), [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/shows) or [Veoh](http://www.veoh.com/) aren't available all around the world.

I know websites like ninjavideo, but they're off course not very legal, so I guess they are out of the question.

So does anyone know a good alternative to Hulu, Veoh or Youtube, where you can watch streaming movies?

Comment: [Zattoo](http://zattoo.com) streams TV.

Comment: For Hulu access outside the US without a proxy: http://lifehacker.com/5583515/access-hulu-from-outside-the-us-without-a-proxy-server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking to

- Upload HD content
- Just watch music videos
- Looking for lol videos
- Watch movies
- Filter the *youtube community* that spams the top videos

I used to like [Dailymotion](http://www.dailymotion.com) but for some reason I would get a lot of videos in french or french subtitles. It was great for watching full movies and music videos (they have not signed up with Vevo so I am sure there are no content blocks ? you will have to update the questions with links from YouTube Vevo to check)

[Vimeo](http://vimeo.com) is my all time favorite for watching high quality content. No Fred, No trolls talking about religion, no Emo guys just plain high quality videos shot on the best cameras money can buy.

They are [others](http://www.metacafe.com/) which may be good as well but they tend to be filled with lots of pron, low quality content and ads.

If you are surf a lot of videos, you can try [Google Videos](http://video.google.com/) as well which is a collection of video sites.

Answer (score 0):

[BlinkBox](http://blinkbox.com) streams TV and movies in certain regions. They offer free content with adverts as well as ad-free rental and purchases.

Answer (score 0):

TVCatchup is far better than Zattoo, and have iPhone (iDevice) streaming. In high quality, all for free. Blinkbox.com is also excellent.

Comment: tvcatchup is UK only

Comment: thats why zattoo is just better in germany :)

Answer (score 0):

I use two sites primarily for finding video and TV content. I have never really liked YouTube much, however I do enjoy [vimeo.com](http://vimeo.com). It just seems to have a better user experience, and seems to have a more mature audience and membership.

When it comes to TV shows, [NetFlix](http://netflix.com) has a lot to offer. They have a considerable amount of TV shows available in their `Instant Watch` library, and the quality (particularly with their SilverLight player) is quite phenomenal. No commercials, either. :)

Answer (score 0):

I use [iTVmediaPlayer](http://itvmediaplayer.com/). It is an open TV platform from all over the world; containing more than 200,000 TV channels! :)